# Error: Please pass numbers as strings or BN objects to avoid precision errors

Tags: smartcontracts, metamask

```
<tbody>
    <tr style={{color: 'white'}}>
        <td>{window.web3.utils.fromWei(this.props.stakingBalance, 'ether')} USDT</td>
        <td>{window.web3.utils.fromWei(this.props.rwdBalance, 'ether')} RWD</td>                       
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Error: Please pass numbers as strings or BN objects to avoid precision errors.
not able to display the stakingBalance and rwdBalance, it asks to pass as strings or BN objects

Answer (score 0):

As the error says "Please pass numbers as strings"

```
<td>{window.web3.utils.fromWei(String(this.props.stakingBalance), 'ether')} USDT</td>
 <td>{window.web3.utils.fromWei(String(this.props.rwdBalance), 'ether')} RWD</td>
```

If you are getting this balances via `await web3.eth.getBalance()` function, this function already returns "string". If so, the problem is somewhere in your code, you might have this function:

```
  web3.utils.toWei("passStringValueHere", "ether")
```

Comment: <td>{window.web3.utils.fromWei(String(this.props.stakingBalance), 'ether')} USDT</td>
<td>{window.web3.utils.fromWei(String(this.props.rwdBalance), 'ether')} RWD</td> 
,-----Error: [number-to-bn] while converting number "undefined" to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance. Note, decimals are not supported. I'm getting this error, can you please help me through this.